Error when performing pod install command
I installed Flutter with following the documentation at their website but when I want to run it and perform pod install I get this error. I tried changing version of Cocoapods but it doesn't work. Does anyone have an idea?
Analyzing dependencies
firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '10.20.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.20.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
<internal:/Users/name/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': cannot load such file -- xcodeproj (LoadError)
        from <internal:/Users/name/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from /Users/name/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_crashlytics-3.4.13/ios/crashlytics_add_upload_symbols:1:in `<main>'
firebase_crashlytics: Using Firebase SDK version '10.20.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_dynamic_links: Using Firebase SDK version '10.20.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_performance: Using Firebase SDK version '10.20.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
Downloading dependencies
Installing Firebase (10.20.0)
Installing FirebaseABTesting (10.27.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (10.20.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (10.20.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreExtension (10.27.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreInternal (10.27.0)
Installing FirebaseCrashlytics (10.20.0)
Installing FirebaseDynamicLinks (10.20.0)
Installing FirebaseInstallations (10.27.0)
Installing FirebasePerformance (10.20.0)
Installing FirebaseRemoteConfig (10.27.0)
Installing FirebaseRemoteConfigInterop (10.27.0)
Installing FirebaseSessions (10.27.0)
Installing FirebaseSharedSwift (10.27.0)
Installing Flutter (1.0.0)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (2.3.0)
Installing GoogleAppMeasurement (10.20.0)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (9.4.1)
Installing GoogleMLKit (4.0.0)
Installing GoogleToolboxForMac (2.3.2)
Installing GoogleUtilities (7.13.3)
Installing GoogleUtilitiesComponents (1.1.0)
Installing MLImage (1.0.0-beta4)
Installing MLKitBarcodeScanning (3.0.0)
Installing MLKitCommon (9.0.0)
Installing MLKitTextRecognition (2.0.0)
Installing MLKitTextRecognitionCommon (1.0.0)
Installing MLKitVision (5.0.0)
Installing PromisesObjC (2.4.0)
Installing PromisesSwift (2.4.0)
Installing ReachabilitySwift (5.2.3)
Installing ScreenProtectorKit (1.3.1)
Installing camera_avfoundation (0.0.1)
Installing connectivity_plus (0.0.1)
Installing device_info_plus (0.0.1)
Installing firebase_analytics (10.8.4)
Installing firebase_core (2.25.3)
Installing firebase_crashlytics (3.4.13)
Installing firebase_dynamic_links (5.4.12)
Installing firebase_performance (0.9.3-12)
Installing flutter_native_splash (0.0.1)
Installing flutter_nfc_kit (2.0.0)
Installing flutter_secure_storage (6.0.0)
Installing google_mlkit_barcode_scanning (0.9.0)
Installing google_mlkit_commons (0.5.0)
Installing google_mlkit_text_recognition (0.10.0)
Installing libPhoneNumber-iOS (0.9.15)
Installing libphonenumber (0.0.1)
Installing nanopb (2.30909.1)
Installing package_info_plus (0.4.5)
Installing path_provider_foundation (0.0.1)
Installing permission_handler_apple (9.1.1)
Installing rive_common (0.0.1)
Installing screen_brightness_ios (0.1.0)
Installing screen_protector (1.2.1)
Installing share_plus (0.0.1)
Installing shared_preferences_foundation (0.0.1)
Installing smart_auth (0.0.1)
Installing sqflite (0.0.3)
Installing url_launcher_ios (0.0.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

Command
/usr/local/bin/pod install

Report

What did you do?

What did you expect to happen?

What happened instead?


Stack
   CocoaPods : 1.13.0
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.arm64e-darwin23]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3.1
        Host : macOS 14.5 (23F79)
       Xcode : 15.4 (15F31d)
         Git : git version 2.39.3 (Apple Git-146)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/

Plugins
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0

Podfile
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
        'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',
      ]
    end
  end
end

Error
REXML::ParseException - #<TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected Regexp)>
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/source.rb:220:in `scan'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/source.rb:220:in `match'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/parsers/baseparser.rb:227:in `pull_event'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/parsers/baseparser.rb:207:in `pull'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/parsers/treeparser.rb:23:in `parse'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/document.rb:448:in `build'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/document.rb:101:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.24.0/lib/xcodeproj/workspace.rb:83:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.24.0/lib/xcodeproj/workspace.rb:83:in `from_s'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.24.0/lib/xcodeproj/workspace.rb:66:in `new_from_xcworkspace'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:102:in `create_workspace'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:71:in `integrate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:929:in `block in integrate_user_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:925:in `integrate_user_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:185:in `integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:170:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
...
wrong argument type String (expected Regexp)
Line: 1
Position: 38
Last 80 unconsumed characters:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/parsers/treeparser.rb:96:in `rescue in parse'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/parsers/treeparser.rb:21:in `parse'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/document.rb:448:in `build'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/document.rb:101:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.24.0/lib/xcodeproj/workspace.rb:83:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.24.0/lib/xcodeproj/workspace.rb:83:in `from_s'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.24.0/lib/xcodeproj/workspace.rb:66:in `new_from_xcworkspace'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:102:in `create_workspace'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:71:in `integrate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:929:in `block in integrate_user_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:925:in `integrate_user_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:185:in `integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:170:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Well I see this error cannot load such file -- xcodeproj, so you need to gem install xcodeproj See Here

engineersmnky thank you, it did fix that error but not the rest of the error.

Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78619414/cocoapods-xcworkspace-file-is-missing-with-error/78873566#78873566

The main reason for this error is because you're using the system Ruby (the Ruby version that came preinstalled on your Mac). The system Ruby is not meant to be used for development. It's for Apple's use only, and modifying it (by installing gems such as Cocoapods) might break things on your Mac.
Here are two sites that explain in detail why you shouldn't use the System Ruby on a Mac:
Why You Shouldn't Use the System Ruby to Install Gems on a Mac
Don't Use System Ruby
Instead, I highly recommend installing a separate and newer version of Ruby using a version manager (such as chruby, rbenv, asdf, rvm). Here's a step by step guide for properly installing Ruby on a Mac.
And if you want to learn more about how Ruby works and why you're getting this specific error related to REXML, read this detailed article:
https://www.rubyonmac.dev/cocoapods-rexml-parse-exception
Finally, although you might see a lot of people telling you to use sudo to install gems, I highly discourage that. When you have a proper Ruby development environment, sudo is absolutely never needed. I've been working with Ruby for more than 12 years, and not once have I had to use sudo to install any gem.
Here's an article that explains Why You Should Never Use sudo to Install Ruby Gems.

Had similar issue and did the following to resolve:
Could you show the output of gem list?
The following command lines may be another workaround:
$ sudo gem install rexml -v 3.2.6
$ sudo gem uninstall rexml -v 3.2.9

The following command lines may be another workaround:
$ sudo gem install strscan

then run pod install again after running the above command.

Thank you so much this solved this for me, I guess it is particular to Macbook Pro M3 chip

No, it is not particular to the M3 chip. The error is due to using the version of Ruby that comes preinstalled on all Macs. See my answer for more details. While this solution might work, it is highly discouraged to keep using the system Ruby, and even more discouraged to use "sudo" to install gems.

Fixed it by upgrading cocoapods from 1.13.0 to 1.15.2. Ran flutter clean, flutter pub get and removed the pods folder. After that ran pod install again and everything worked

STEP 01:
Run the following commands:
$ sudo gem install rexml -v 3.2.6

$ sudo gem uninstall rexml -v 3.2.9

STEP 02:
Run the following commands:
$ sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

$ arch -x86_64 pod install

At last, run flutter run. It should work.
