Cocoapods xcworkspace file is missing with error
Using Terminal to create Cocoapods in my project.
But after the command the .xcworkspace is missing ...
Command
/usr/local/bin/pod install

Stack
CocoaPods : 1.15.2
Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
RubyGems : 3.0.3
Host : Mac OS X 10.15.7 (19H15)
Xcode : 12.4 (12D4e)
Git : git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
Plugins
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
Report

What did you do? pod install

What did you expect to happen? create a file .xcworkspace

What happened instead? .xcworkspace is missing and with this error message [!] Oh no, an error occurred.


Podfile
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Flash Chat iOS13' do

  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Flash Chat iOS13

pod 'CLTypingLabel'

end

Error
REXML::ParseException - #<TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected Regexp)>
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/source.rb:220:in scan' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/source.rb:220:in match'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/parsers/baseparser.rb:227:in pull_event' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/parsers/baseparser.rb:207:in pull'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/parsers/treeparser.rb:23:in parse' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/document.rb:448:in build'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/document.rb:101:in initialize' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.24.0/lib/xcodeproj/workspace.rb:50:in new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.24.0/lib/xcodeproj/workspace.rb:50:in initialize' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:111:in new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:111:in create_workspace' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:71:in integrate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:929:in block in integrate_user_project' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:925:in integrate_user_project' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:185:in integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:170:in install!' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in <top (required)>' /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `'
...
wrong argument type String (expected Regexp)
Line: 1
Position: 38
Last 80 unconsumed characters:
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/parsers/treeparser.rb:96:in rescue in parse' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/parsers/treeparser.rb:21:in parse'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/document.rb:448:in build' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/document.rb:101:in initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.24.0/lib/xcodeproj/workspace.rb:50:in new' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.24.0/lib/xcodeproj/workspace.rb:50:in initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:111:in new' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:111:in create_workspace'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:71:in integrate!' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:929:in block in integrate_user_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in section' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:925:in integrate_user_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:185:in integrate' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:170:in install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in load' /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in '

I am building on Flutter + Dart and ran into the same problem. Pod installation was failing.
To fix this, uninstall cocoapods and ffi. Re-install cocoapods but you might need to remove existing link and re-link to new location.

sudo gem uninstall cocoapods && gem uninstall ffi
brew install cocoapods
brew link --overwrite cocoapods

